# HTML CSS - Undraggable Image and Neat Codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help im working on a web development im kinda new into this, but how do i make image undraggable, i already made it undraggable, but when i select all texts and whole page and this image, it makes in draggable state help.

[drag image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3N05.jpg)

and i need suggestions or critics. IS MY WORK NEAT? is it clean or what? thanks everyone :)

```css
body {
  background-color: #CEF6CE;
}
* {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 height: 642px;
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.login {
 background-color: red;
 width: 235px;
 height: 295px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 margin-left: 545px;
 margin-right: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.loginform {
 margin-top: 25px;
}
.txts td {
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.footer {
 background-color: #4A4A4A;
 width: 100%;
 height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 bottom: 0;
 font-size: 11px;
}
.copyright {
 background-color: transparent;
 position: absolute;
 color: #E0E0E0;
 margin-left: 1000px;
}
a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
button.loginBtn {
 width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #3399ff;
    border-color: #3399ff;
    border-radius: 3px;

}
button.loginBtn:hover {
 background-color: #1a8cff;
}
a.frgtPass {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: red;
}
a.frgtPass:hover {
 color: #ff6666;
}
p.frmt {
 color: #757575;
}
p.frmtnum {
 color: #8898B5;
}
input.inputs {
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
 height: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
img.logo {
 pointer-events: none;
 margin-top: 150px;
 margin-left: 75px;
 position: absolute;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Insight - Saint Vincent High School Community Portal</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\main_design.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="main">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <img class="logo" src="img/smple.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
  <div class="login">
   <table class="txts">
    <tr>
     <td><p>Saint Vincent High School</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><p>Online Community Portal</p></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <div class="loginform">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><p style="font-size:15px">Username / ID</p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="username" size="30"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><p style="font-size:15px">Password</p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="password" size="30"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><button type="submit" style="cursor: pointer" class="loginBtn">Login</button>
      <a class="frgtPass" href=" " style="font-size:12px">Forgot password?</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><br><p class="frmt" style="font-size:16px">Student ID format:</p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><p class="frmtnum" style="font-size:16px">101-2016-0000</p></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="footer">
  <div class="copyright">
   <table class="txts" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
     <td>Insight &#169; 2016</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <table cellpadding="4">
   <tr>
    <td><a href=" " style="color: #E0E0E0">About</a></td>
    <td><font color="#E0E0E0">&bull;</font></td>
    <td><a href=" " style="color: #E0E0E0">Privacy</a></td>
    <td><font color="#E0E0E0">&bull;</font></td>
    <td><a href=" " style="color: #E0E0E0">Terms</a></td>
    <td><font color="#E0E0E0">&bull;</font></td>
    <td><a href=" " style="color: #E0E0E0">Help</a></td>
    <td><font color="#E0E0E0">&bull;</font></td>
    <td><a href=" " style="color: #E0E0E0">Feedback</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In case it is working well, then it might be better fit for the [codereview site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Tip #1: Don't use tables. Learn bootstrap as it's much easier and will be responsive if implemented correctly.
- Tip #2: Try and avoid the color red unless it is really needed. This color makes people think there are errors and scares users off very quickly.
- Tip #3: Ensure logins and passwords are secure as these can be hacked very quickly and easily.
- Tip #4: Use colors that compliment one another.

Regarding your question, you can set the CSS properties for the image

```
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
user-drag: none; 
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```